# Select buildings in a html map and get osm

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap

I have my own database of buildings with the architects and some metadata. In the past I tied them manually to the ID of openstreetmap.

But now I need a map where I can click on a shape of building or area and getting the id into Javascript for processing more. (its functionality is near to the edit mode of openstreetmap). I already read about leaflet and openlayers but as I recognized there is always the query of lat/lon and not getting the real id from the object underneath the cursors. That is not so nice because I have to very often select a specific shape or id.

Is there anything which might help me or already exists to build something like that? I can not imagine that it might not possible!

Comment: I think this presentation on serving OSM Vector Tiles might be along the lines of what you're looking for: http://www.slideshare.net/OSMFstateofthemap/diy-osm-pbf-vector-tiles-state-of-the-map-2013

Comment: I already saw this. But I do not know before whether I want to select buildings, squares, roads, parks etc. That would mean that i have to overlay the whole map itself?

Comment: This appears to be along the lines of what you're talking about: http://www.slideshare.net/OSMFstateofthemap/diy-osm-pbf-vector-tiles-state-of-the-map-2013

Comment: wow great thats exactly what I need. Thanks for this. Do you want to write it as answer or even editing your one?

Comment: Glad to hear it! I changed my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Well I contacted the author and the project is currently not in a futher development.

Comment: I wasn't sure you'd have an out of the box solution with that, but you could build something to your needs using the code referenced. There seem to be a lot of ideas floating around regarding vector tiles--it does look like MapBox will render custom ones if you don't want to wade through it all.